How can I disable context indentation
I have a cpp file that I am editing. I have set the tab-stop-list to the columns every three characters at the top of .emacs. I also do a global-set-key of the TAB character to be tab-to-tab-stop. In the cpp file, when I type a '(' character after the 'printf' string, emacs removes one character from the current indentation. Seems to me it preserved the first tab stop and removed one character from the second.
I am trying to disable context related indentation either globally or through a hook, but its not working. Below is my .emacs. I am on Sparc Solaris 9 with GNU Emacs 23.3.1.
(custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.                                                                                              
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.                                                                           
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.                                                                                  
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.                                                                                      
  '(c-label-minimum-indentation 3)
  '(tab-stop-list (quote (3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57 60 63 66 69 72 75 78 81))))
(custom-set-faces
  ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.                                                                                                  
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.                                                                           
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.                                                                                  
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.                                                                                      
 )
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'tab-to-tab-stop)
(normal-erase-is-backspace-mode 1)
(cua-mode 1)
(defun makefile-config ()
   (global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'self-insert-command))
(add-hook 'makefile-gmake-mode-hook #'makefile-config)
(setq c-syntatic-indentation nil)
(setq c-electric-paren nil)
(setq parens-require-spaces nil)
(defun cpp-config ()
        (global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'tab-to-tab-stop)
        (setq-default c-basic-offset 3)
        (setf indent-line-function #'indent-relative-maybe)
        )
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook #'cpp-config)

The source code I am editing is :
void DSStartFromConfigOne::run(char* pathToConfig) {

   DSStoragePoolCoordinator* coord = new DSStoragePoolCoordinator(pathToConfig);
   std::map<int, std::string> errors = coord->errorCodesToMessages();

   std::map<int, std::string>::iterator errorIt = errors.begin();
   for (errorIt = errors.begin(); it != errors.end(); it++) {
     printf(
   }
}

as you can see, the first character of printf is under the r key of the for on the line above. It should under the space after the for.
Thanks,
Regards
